# Determining type of hours worked past certain time of day

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Link to sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dwpeRWkkbX0adBeQkwMUI6PQa6WqRCNzNluSOw0RU5k/edit?usp=sharing

Our business pays a different rate for drive time vs. site time. We also pay overtime (over 8 hours), and double overtime (over 12 hours). Sometimes we also have a crew going to several different job sites in a day (no more than 7). Therefore I can have several different pay categories:

- Drive
- Site
- Drive (Overtime)
- Site (Overtime)
- Drive (Double Overtime)
- Site (Double Overtime)

Using IF and AND in combination I can determine Site (DOT) and Drive (DOT). My issue is properly determining Drive (OT) and Site (OT). I have somewhat of a solution in mind using IFS and AND in combination but it seems cumbersome and clunky. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

I have formulas in cells on the sheet listing total hours, hours after break, total overtime, etc.

Here is what a selection of the times looks like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to get `double overtime`, you should be able to get `overtime` with this logic:

`overtime` === `total time` – `8 Hours W/Break` – `double overtime`

Your sample spreadsheet shows that you are using "digital hours" that look like `6.75` instead of durations like `6:45`. It is usually simpler to stick to durations. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.