# To fetch stock price day's high and low for a range of days including today

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

For shares listed on NSE I am unable to get Day's high and low while using below query if the start day and end date is same or today.

High:
`=MAX(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:INFY", "ALL",06/05/2021 ,06/05/2021),"select Col3",1))`

Low:
`=MIN(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:INFY", "ALL",06/05/2021 ,06/05/2021),"select Col4",1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `06/05/2021` is not a date but a quotient whose value is 6 divided by 5 divided by 2021, e.g., `0.0005937654626`.

Since the question was posted on 6 May 2021, I am assuming that you want to express the date `2021-05-06`. To get a dateserial value, replace the hard-coded value with a reference to a cell that contains a date, or use an expression like `value("2021-05-06")`, as in the following examples.

Get the maximum `High` and the minimum `Low` for a single day:

```
=query( 
  googlefinance("NSE:INFY", "all", value("2021-05-06")), 
  "select max(Col3), min(Col4)", 
  1 
)
```

Get the maximum `High` and the minimum `Low` for a calendar month:

```
=query( 
  googlefinance( 
    "NSE:INFY", 
    "all", 
    value("2021-05-06"), 
    day(eomonth(value("2021-05-06"), 0)) 
  ), 
  "select max(Col3), min(Col4)", 
  1 
)
```

As said, this is usually done by using a reference to a cell that contains a date, rather than using a hard-coded value embedded in the formula, like this:

```
=iferror( 
  query( 
    googlefinance( 
      "NSE:" & A2, 
      "all", 
      G2, 
      H2 - G2 + 1 
    ), 
    "select max(Col3), min(Col4) 
     label max(Col3) '', min(Col4) '' ", 
    1 
  ), 
  "(no data for '" & A2 & "' " & trim(G2) & " - " & trim(H2) & ")" 
)
```

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Comment: sorry but it is not working in my query

=MAX(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:INFY", "ALL",value("2021-05-01") ,value("2021-05-01")),"select Col3",1)) -- High

=MIN(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:INFY", "ALL",value("2021-05-01") ,value("2021-05-01")),"select Col4",1))--Low

Comment: Edited the answer to show how to make it work. The problem in your formula is that the start date and the end date are the same.

Comment: Hi please find a link for my Test sheet, where i am using the date as cell reference still i am unable to get high/low other than row 1. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vrSdjJQDM0-JxhXBerV13G8bO2SN6d-I9JxzGgRAAXg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Edited the answer to show how to do this with your spreadsheet.