# IFNA() doesn't work with date format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have this table :

[image]

column **F** is my data and column **H** is to check if column **F** has **N/A** error. In **H1** i use this formula :

```
ifna(F1,"error")
```

Seems to work fine. But in the 2nd row when it check the date , it returns a number instead of a date.
How can I fix this ?

Comment: The `ifna()` function returns its first argument, unless that argument is an `#N/A` error, in which case it returns the second argument. It is unclear what you expect the output to be. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: @doubleunary That H2 should return 7/12/2021 not 44389. I don't know where that 44389 come from.

Comment: `44389` is the dateserial value for `7/12/2021`. Edited the answer to return what you want. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Comment: The number 44389 is the number of elapsed days since December 30, 1899 — the date that Google Sheets uses as "ground zero" in marking time. Just format the date cell/range as a date in the format of your choice. An easy way, given your particular sheet, would be to click on a cell that contains a date already in the format you like (e.g., F2), click the paintbrush icon in the menu (far left), then click the new cell (or click and drag across a range) to "paint" that format to the new cells. Otherwise, select the cell/range and then choose Format > Number > Date (format of your choice).

Comment: [old question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/155732/) but never properly answered.  See [my solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169627/) that addresses *your* specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to detect `#N/A` errors:

`=arrayformula( if( isna(F1:F), "error", F1:F ) )`

The formula will give `error` when a cell in column `F` is an `#N/A` error, and the value in column `F` otherwise.

Comment: i mean i want  H2 to be 7/12/2021 not 44389.

Answer (score 0):

From [Erik Tyler](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/197265/erik-tyler)'s [answer-as-a-comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/155732/ifna-doesnt-work-with-date-format#comment142133_155732) (with some reformatting):

> Just format the date cell/range as a date in the format of your
> choice.
>
> An easy way, given your particular sheet, would be to click on a cell
> that contains a date already in the format you like (e.g., F2), click
> the paintbrush icon in the menu (far left), then click the new cell
> (or click and drag across a range) to "paint" that format to the new
> cells.
>
> Otherwise, select the cell/range and then choose Format > Number >
> Date (format of your choice).

Also from that comment:

> The number 44389 is the number of elapsed days since December 30, 1899
> — the date that Google Sheets uses as "ground zero" in marking time.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP($E5,qStock!$D$1:qStock!$H$98,3,FALSE),"")
```

was my formula which I had the same problem.

As doubleunery says, I changed it to:

`=arrayformula( if( isna(VLOOKUP($E5,qStock!$D$1:qStock!$H$98,3,FALSE)), "", VLOOKUP($E5,qStock!$D$1:qStock!$H$98,3,FALSE ) )`

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Click **Reveal Spoiler** to see solution immediately*</sub>

> =IFNA(IF(ISDATE(A1),TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),A1),"error")

---

The formula `=IFNA(<startValue>,"error")` is designed to return the text string "error" if `<startValue>` is a `#N/A` error, or `<startValue>` if not.

The formula worked for all the questionnner's use cases except for dates, and they sought a way to adapt the formula to avoid returning a number when the `<startValue>` is a date.
[image]

As has been pointed out, the original formula is sound but is returning the DATEVALUE `44389` instead of the date-formatted versaion of that number: `7/12/2021`
[image]

It isn't appropriate to format the column values as dates since that would introduce a new problem in cases wherever the `<startValue>` is a non-date number. Selectively formatting cells is not a good idea since values can change, and it can also be time consuming and prone to error as the dataset size increases.
[image]

## Solution

The appropriate solution is simple and extensible.  It is to determine if the `<statValue>` is a date, and if so, format it as such within the formula.

1. `ISDATE(value)` will return TRUE for dates
2. `TEXT(value, "mm/dd/yyyy")/1` returns a date-formatted number.  Dividing the result by 1 is what coerces the text date back to a number.
3. By testing if `<startValue>` is a date, the formula can be adapted to return one of 3 values: `"error"`  *or*  `<startValue>`  *or*  `<startValue> as a date-formatted number`

```
# where <startValue> is in A1

=IFNA(IF(ISDATE(A1),
         TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),
         A1),
      "error")
```

[image]
[image]

## BYROW Version

For a single cell solution, BYROW can be combined with a LAMBDA function that contains the formula but replaces the cell references with an arbitrary name (variable) `r` to represent each row that the formula is applied to.

```
=BYROW(A:A, LAMBDA(r,IF(r<>"",
    IFNA(IF(ISDATE(r),TEXT(r,"mm/dd/yyyy"),r),
         "error"),
)))
```

[image]