# Help with Getting the Difference of two dates or displaying NA in cell if no date entered

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to Fetch the difference between two dates in different cells, or if the first cell is empty display nothing.

`=DATEDIF(E9,H3, "D")OR(ISBLANK(E8))`
Is what i have been playing with but i keep getting an error
if i simply use `=DATEDIF(E9,H3, "D")` the cell returns a very high number

Comment: Your formula attempts to compare dates in E9 and H3, but looking to see if E8 is blank. But this doesn't match your post description of "if the first cell is empty, display nothing." The most efficient way to get help is to share a link to your sheet (or a copy of it), so that we can see all the pieces in context (which are more than you might think). For instance, right now, it's not clear what is being compared, whether you are trying to process multiple rows or just one, whether either E9 or H3 are a static reference against which other dates will all be compared, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`=if(isdate(H3) * isdate(E9), H3 - E9, iferror(1/0))`

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.