# How to add a date ,from a cell, into a sentence of another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

Hopefully the title isn't too confusing, but basically I have two cells containing dates and I want to write a sentence in another cell using those dates. I know that to do this with things that aren't dates you just type in the cell:

`="Today is, " & A2 & " Tomorrow is " & B2 & "!"`
Where A2 and B2 are strings or numbers.

But when I do the same thing with the dates, it gives me numbers instead of the actual dates (I believe this number is the number of days since 1899). Is there a way to format the dates as, well dates inside of the sentence? I tried DATEVALUE but it didn't work because the cells being referenced aren't strings. Maybe I could convert the referenced cells into strings inside of the function and then use DATEVALUE?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cells `A2` and `B2` already have the dates in the format you need, you can just use this:

`="Today is " & trim(A2) & ", and tomorrow is " & trim(B2)`

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I can use TEXT().

Using the example from last time, I would use the following:

`="Today is, " & TEXT(A2, "MM/DD/YYYY") & " Tomorrow is " & TEXT(B2, "MM/DD/YYYY") & "!"`