# Round up duration calculation to the next multiple of five minutes

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I currently have this formula:

`=text(D2 - C2, "hh:mm:ss")`

I need this formula to round **up** to the nearest 5 minutes.

I have tried `mround()`, `ceiling()` and `roundup()`, but I'm not getting the result I need.

Comment: The requirement to use `text()` sounds superfluous. Please confirm whether you need the result to be a duration, or a text string that just _looks like_ a duration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=mround((D2 - C2) * 24 * 60 + 5, 5) / 24 / 60`

Format the result cell as **Format > Number > Duration** or another time number format of your choosing.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.