# How to SUM the VLOOKUP results based on condition in other column using ARRAYFORMULA?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

[image]
[image]

I would like to sum all the costs based on the products purchased between specific dates.

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP('Purchased List Table'!B2:B,'Pricing Table'!A2:B,2,0),"")))
```

With the formula above, I managed to sum all the prices of all products in the **Purchased List Table** instead of a certain timeframe.

How could I modify the formula in order to sum only the costs of products within specific timeframe (e.g.: between 9/3/2021 to 9/5/2021 only)?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()` or `query()` to choose which search keys to include, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  sum( 
    iferror( 
      vlookup(
        filter( 
          'Purchased List Table'!B2:B, 
          "2021-09-03" <= 'Purchased List Table'!A2:A, 
          'Purchased List Table'!A2:A <= "2021-09-05" 
        ), 
        'Pricing Table'!A2:B, 
        columns('Pricing Table'!A2:B), 
        false 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: It works! Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Dates in Australia are formatted d-m-y compared to the US: m-d-y. Try as I might, I can't seem to adapt the formula for Australian dates. Possibly just a simple mistake on my part, but how would you suggest that the formula would appear if the spreadsheet locale was "Australia".

Comment: Date _format_ has no effect on formulas that examine those dates. They see date serial values that are the same regardless of the format used. The ISO8601 format `yyyy-mm-dd` works the same everywhere. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219).

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUMPRODUCT`

**Date range in the spreadsheet**
`=sumproduct($B$2:$B$4,arrayformula(COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$9,A2:A4,$D$2:$D$9,">="&$H$2,$D$2:$D$9,"<="&$H$3)))`

**Date range in the formula**

`=sumproduct($B$2:$B$4,arrayformula(COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$9,A2:A4,$D$2:$D$9,">=3/9/2021",$D$2:$D$9,"<=5/9/2021")))`

---

**Sample**

[image: Screenshot]