# Sum Duration with google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

How can i sum duration with google sheet?
I need to sum this value

```
1:14:127
1:14:057
1:13:938
1:13:894
```

I set the cell with duration "mm,ss,SSS" and i try this formula
=sum(a1:a4) and
=TEXT(a1:a4 ,"mm:ss:SSS")

but i receive always error message

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0):

If the values really are numeric durations, you can add them together with `sum()` or regular addition `+`.

If the values are text strings that just look like durations, you should convert them to durations before working with them. See if the `value()` function can get a number out, and if so, format the result as **Format > Number > Duration**.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.