# I want date with yyyy/mm/dd format on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-cell-format

[image]

I want to convert mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd with function on Google Sheets.

I applied TEXT function like the picture but it's not working.
How can I convert this?

Comment: Using TEXT() function converts it to string and you won't be able to use it as a date anymore is you need. Try Format\Number\Custom date and time format where you can choose from premade formats or make your own. This way it will still be a date and you can use other functions on it.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Answer (score 1):

Since `text()` is returning the value without change, chances are that the value is not a numeric date but a *text string* that just looks like a date. Set **File > Settings > Locale** to the real locale you want to use, and re-enter the dates in local format.

If you have many such dates to convert, use a formula to convert them, like this:

`=to_date(value(regexreplace(trim(D28), "(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)", "$3-$1-$2")))`

Format the resulting dateserials as **Format > Number > Date** or another date format of your choosing. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Comment: hi, I did not understand this part of your calculation:
"$3-$1-$2" also because I get the same result by modifying it or placing it empty. Could you kindly explain it to me?
(test sheet at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qOrlLECmPQ4HrcYvvyfarz4ybGzJD752dUTnBjjfL0A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `$3-$1-$2` signifies the third, first and second capturing group, respectively. See [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).

Comment: Your [test spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qOrlLECmPQ4HrcYvvyfarz4ybGzJD752dUTnBjjfL0A/edit#gid=0) is in the United States locale that uses `m/d/yyyy` by default, so the dates there are already interpreted correctly. Your question suggests that your real spreadsheet is in another locale such as France, where that format will result in many dates entered as becoming text strings that just look like dates. The formula will convert such text strings, and incorrect numeric date values, into a date, assuming that those incorrect values should be interpreted as `d/m/yyyy`.

Comment: i got it, thank you very much