# I have two time columns in Google Sheets. Need to know if the time in column 1 is <=24 hours prior to the time in column 2 or > than 24 hours

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

Please help me get this IF statement right, my brain is fried.

I have several different columns to describe aspects of my Shift IDs which is Column A.

One of these columns is cancellation time of a shift, another is shift start time.

I need to know if cancellation time is within 24 hours before the start time or more than 24 hours before the start time.

Some of the cancellations take place after the start time if this impacts things.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0):

You can find if the start time in cell `S2` is more than 24 hours after the cancellation time in cell `C2` by inserting this formula in a free cell in row `2`:

`=S2 - C2 > 1`

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.