# Google Spreadsheet calculate the minutes between 14:00-15:00 and then all other minutes between 15-21

Tags: google-sheets

In one cell I put a shift time, for example 1400-2100 and here's what I want to do

If the shift starts **before** 15:00, 13:00, I want it to print in one cell the number of minutes between 13:00-15:00, in this example 60 min. AND in another cell print the number of minutes between 15:00-21:00.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0):

Use these formulas to find the durations:

```
=min( "15:00", value( regexreplace(trim(A2), ".*\-\s*(\d\d).*$", "$1") & ":" & regexreplace(trim(A2), ".*(\d\d)$", "$1") ) )
 - 
 max( "13:00", value( value( regexreplace(trim(A2), "^\s*(\d\d).*", "$1") & ":" & regexreplace(trim(A2), ".*(\d\d)\s*\-.*$", "$1") ) ) )
```

```
=min( "22:00", value( regexreplace(trim(A2), ".*\-\s*(\d\d).*$", "$1") & ":" & regexreplace(trim(A2), ".*(\d\d)$", "$1") ) )
 - 
 max( "15:00", value( value( regexreplace(trim(A2), "^\s*(\d\d).*", "$1") & ":" & regexreplace(trim(A2), ".*(\d\d)\s*\-.*$", "$1") ) ) )
```

Format the result cells as **Format > Number > Duration**.

If you really need to get the number of minutes as a decimal number, multiply the results by `24 * 60` as in `=B2 * 24 * 60`, and format these results as **Format > Number > Number**.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.