# Converting ARRAYFORMULA to range for SUMIF

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that `IMPORTRANGE`'s data from another spreadsheet, which contains a column with numerical values that are of type string. In another sheet I am trying to sum the values in that column using `SUMIF`. The command is the following:

```
=SUMIF(Transactions!G2:G, "Food & Dining", ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(Transactions!D2:D)))
```

Where column `G` contains text to check, and column `D` contains the numbers of type string. Of course, I need those values to be numbers to sum them up, so I added the `ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(...))` to try to make it a range, but it tells me that the "Argument must be a range". I'm fairly new to Google Sheets, so I'm confused as to why doesn't it consider this a valid range? When I use that `ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(...))` command on its own it returns a range of values, so how come in `SUMIF` its not valid? Is there a way to achieve this, or maybe some easier way by adding a rule that every cell in `D` be converted to a number?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: A "range" and an "array" are not the same thing. A range is a reference to a specific location in a spreadsheet and *only* that location. Once you start to try to process the *data* in that range, you've formed a virtual *array* of the data and are no longer referring to the range. Since the `VALUES` of the data in your range are not contained in an actual range of the spreadsheet, `SUMIF` doesn't "know" what to do with them. As you haven't shared a link to the spreadsheet, that's as much specific information as I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment to your original post. That said, there are other functions that could be used to obtain the result you are after. For instance:

`=ArrayFormula(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Transactions!D2:D),1,0),IF(Transactions!G2:G="Food & Dining",Transactions!D2:D*1,0)))`

`MMULT` performs **M**atrix **MULT**iplication. If you don't know what that is, it is too complex to explain here. But all you need to know for your purposes is that it's an alternative to `SUMIF` as you are trying to use it. Adapting the components should be obvious.

The `*1` in the formula is converting strings to numbers (and if numbers already exist, it will just return the number anyway).

Answer (score 1):

The `sumif()` function requires a range. You should apply `value()` already when *importing* the data, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    value(importrange("...", "Sheet1!A1:D")), 
    importrange("...", "Sheet1!A1:D") 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: I try this, but the first column has date values so when I import the data the dates get converted from say "2022-05-24" to "44705". How can I prevent this command from running `VALUE` on the date column (column A)?

Comment: EDIT: I did this myself by just writing a custom App Script function to convert the column with the numbers in the `IMPORTRANGE` data from string to numbers. But, if there is a way to do it all within Google Sheets I am still interested to know.

Comment: Format column `A` as **Format > Number > Date**. The format will stick as the data updates. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.