# Countifs between 2 dates from an import range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates, importrange

Looking for some help on a Countifs formula from an import range (if this is the right thing to use(?))

I have a sheet tracking rejected bookings on certain dates, and I want to pull this into another sheet where I am tracking total bookings, so I can find out the %.

I have a booking sheet which has the date input and the reason for rejected booking. I used an import range to pull all this data into the sheet I am working from, then tried to use a countifs between to dates to see how many for each week.

I used the following:
`=countifs('Rejections'!B:B,">=24/01/2022,'Rejections'B:B,"<=30/1/2022)`

I am referencing the column B containing the dates in (so they read 05/05/2022 for example).
For some reason it is just giving zeros despite there being inputs for those dates.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three syntax errors in your formula: a missing exclamation mark and two missing double quotes.

The date format you show will only work when the spreadsheet locale matches it. To best avoid confusion whether `12/1` means 1st of December (month/day) or 12 January (day/month), make sure that **File > Settings > Locale** matches your real locale, and use the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard date format `yyyy-mm-dd` consistently everywhere.

Try this:

`=countifs( Rejections!B1:B, ">= 2022-01-24", Rejections!B1:B, "<= 2022-01-30" )`

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.