# Standard deviation shows a strange value when computed on duration datatypes

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following durations:

```
0:01:46
0:01:40
0:00:55
0:01:09
0:01:48
0:01:10
0:01:11
0:01:58
```

I converted them to seconds:

```
106
100
55
69
108
70
71
118
```

When I compute the standard deviation using STDEV I have the following results 0.001151620758   0.0002277104092 0.0002981681565. Clearly, is it not the right solution. I was wondering where is the problem.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). It is unclear what you are trying to do. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Durations are *measured* in units of *days* but *formatted* as elapsed hours, minutes and seconds. If you calculate `stdev()` of those durations,  you get `0.000270548955` which, formatted as a duration with milliseconds, is the same as `0:00:23.375`, i.e., 23 seconds and some.

If you convert the durations to numbers that express seconds, and calculate the `stdev()`, you get `23.37542971` — effectively the same result. The conversion to seconds is not really necessary here.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Comment: ah my fault, thanks a lot for pointing it out