# is Google sheet too basic?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-timestamp

Basically earlier I wanted to extract time from a full "date time" record, and after googling it I literally found nothing you can check for yourself, I found a split option and another option using an add-on (unusable), and for a basic command and not be there on the first Google search was a bit shocking, now before I commit to learning Google sheet, first I want to know is it possible to do the extraction even using a programming language and I'm missing something?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Google Sheets is an application for creating and editing spreadsheets which are very popular for handling and analysing small data sets using formulas among other features. The basic structural element is a grid called sheet. Nowadays Google Sheets could handle up to 10 million cells.  It could be easily extended by using Google Apps Script. If you need further help, please [edit] the question to add some sample data, the expected result and to show what you have tried.

Comment: Google Sheets can do pretty much anything you'd need to do. We don't know what search terms you used, but what you are wanting to do is a pretty common request; so I think you just aren't using the best search terms. We also don't know what your date-time strings look like, where they are in your sheet, your international locale (which determines how formulas are written), etc. As Rubén suggests, we need more details (and I suggest also adding a link to a sample sheet, which will be the most efficient means of *showing* us everything at once).

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `timevalue()` to extract the time of the day from a date time value, like this:

`=timevalue(A2)`

In the event your data does not consist of numeric date time values, but of text strings that just look like date time values, use `regexextract()`, like this:

`=value(regexextract(A2, "\d{1,2}:\d{2}"))`

Format the result as **Format > Number > Time**.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.