# Google Sheets - List values if date in corresponding column is the same as the date in Cell D1

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrays

In Sheet 1 I have a table of orders due for a delivery. Column A is a list of the order numbers, and column H is the delivery date. In Sheet 2, I want to create a list of the order numbers that have a delivery date that is the same as the date in Sheet 2 Cell D1, which already updates itself as required. I have tried a VLookup, but of course this will only return the first value it finds. I have also tried an IFERROR(Filter formula but am struggling to assign the criteria.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168291/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other answers have mentioned, the `FILTER()` function is a good solution here. However, I would include the use `DATEVALUE()` for robustness to different date formats. For example, try this:

`=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A, DATEVALUE(Sheet1!H2:H) = DATEVALUE(D1))`

Below is an example of this formula on a sheet with various date field formats in both the variable date and the dates in the order list, where the order values that should match are highlighted orange, the variable date in blue and the filter results in green. You can see the actual formula used in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: The `datevalue()` function will truncate datetimes to dates only, which indeed is often useful. When all values are dates rather than datetimes, `datevalue()` is superfluous. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) to see why.

Comment: @doubleunary, thanks for the comment! Any idea why the above won't work on those different formats without DATEVALUE()?

Comment: Oh, perhaps the values are not dates but _text strings_ that just look like dates. That's indeed a use case for `datevalue()`. You can find if the "dates" really are numeric dates with the `isdate_strict()` function.

Comment: Ah yeah makes sense, thanks. I didn’t know about isdate_strict() either; appreciate the knowledge!

Comment: The date values are generated by a lookup function from a list of set dates in another tab, so should be date values rather than text strings. However I know the people who'll be using this and would not rule out someone overwriting with a text string that looks like a date, so to have this failsafe built in from the start is advantageous

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `Sheet2`:

```
=filter(Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!H2:H = D1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this formula:

```
=filter(Sheet1!A2:A,D1=Sheet1!H2:H)
```