# Calculate a date in combination with the states of multiple checkboxes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have data in `A2:E2`.

1. `A2` contains a date.
2. `B2` contains a formula.
3. `C2:E2` contain checkboxes.

I'm trying to create a formula in `B2` that returns:

- `A2` + 1 day if `C2` is checked;
- `A2` + 2 days if both `C2` and `D2` are checked.
- `A2` + 6 days if `C2`, `D2` and `E2` are all checked.

I have tried multiple ways, but have never manage to add all conditions.

[image: spreadsheet screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168520/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of a few sample cases. Also show your manually entered desired results in those cases in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ifs()` formula in cell `B2`, like this:

```
=to_date( 
  ifs( 
    not(isdate(A2)); iferror(1/0); 
    C2 * D2 * E2; A2 + 6; 
    C2 * D2; A2 + 2; 
    C2; A2 + 1; 
    true; iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

See [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach.

```
=A2+C2*1+C2*D2*1+C2*D2*E2*4
```

Parentheses are unnecessary but you could add them to make it easier to visualize:

```
=A2+(C2*1)+(C2*D2*1)+(C2*D2*E2*4)
```

If you want to ensure that there is a date in `A2` you could add a test:

```
=ISDATE(A2)*A2+(C2*1)+(C2*D2*1)+(C2*D2*E2*4)
```