# Get the remaining time duration

Tags: google-sheets

so I've created a google sheet wherein on Column A I have a date and a time (01/05/2023 14:46:89 | Yesterday's date and time) Something like this and on Column B, I have (01/06/2023 16:46:00 | Today's date and time)

What I want is to display the remaining time on Column C from column B time how many minutes before reaching the time in column A.

Lastly is, for example, I only have like 5 minutes left before reaching the same time on column A, I want to display a text on column D something like "almost there".

Is this even possible? Thank you.

I want to do it using an "ArrayFormula".

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168596/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data and your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula in cell `C2` to get the absolute difference between the datetime values in columns `A` and `B`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    isnumber(A2:A) * isnumber(B2:B), 
    abs(timevalue(A2:A) - timevalue(B2:B)), 
    iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

...and this in cell `D2`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    isnumber(C2:C) * (C2:C <= timevalue("0:05:00")), 
    "almost there", 
    iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

For this to work, columns `C` and `D` must be blank before you paste in the formulas.

See [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219).

Comment: I have an error "TIMEVALUE parameter '08/01/2023, 09:12:00 am' cannot be parsed to date/time"

Comment: You can parse that value with `timevalue(regexreplace(A2, "[^\d:/ ]", ""))`. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).