# Can I convert abbreviated duration info to timestamp info in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-timestamp

I have the following duration input in Google Spreadsheets and I'd like to get an average of all the inputs. But I couldn't find any way to do it. Does anybody know if it's possible?

The input is: 1d 14h 25m. And I'd like to have this converted to 38:25:00.

Thanks a lot for all the answers.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168682/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data with your manually entered desired results side-by-side. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regexextract, like this:

```
=iferror(regexextract(A2, "(\d+)d"))
+iferror(regexextract(A2, "(\d+)h") / 24)
+iferror(regexextract(A2, "(\d+)m") / 24 / 60)
```

Format the formula cell as **Format > Number > Duration**.

See [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219).