# Calculate time difference considering weekends and working hours

Tags: google-sheets

I hope someone here can help me.
I need to calculate the time difference from incoming emails to replies to the emails. So the response time should be determined. For this I need to subtract the weekends that fall between the arrival and response of the emails. In addition, the daily working time (7 am - 3 pm) must be taken into account.

Example:
Arrival of the email: 02/10/2013 3:45 pm
Answering the email: 02/13/2013 10:45 am
Response time: 3:45 hours

Since the email arrived after 3pm, it will not be processed until the next business day. This starts at 7am, so the time is calculated from 7am to 10:45am.

The arrival date is in field B, the arrival time in field C.
The response date is in field D and the response time is in field E. The response time is to be output in field F.

Can someone help me with the solution?

Comment: does [this reference](https://www.lifewire.com/count-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-3123876) help?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/169304/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data side-by-side your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First determine the effective start day and time, then calculate the duration of time spent between the effective start and end, and in the event the effective start falls in a different day than the end, use [networkdays()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092979) to calculate the number of days between start and end, like this:

```
=map( 
  B2:B20, C2:C20, D2:D20, E2:E20, 
  lambda( 
    startDay, startTime, endDay, endTime, 
    if( 
      startDay * startTime * endDay * endTime * (startDay + startTime <= endDay + endTime), 
      let( 
        businessStart, value("7:00"), businessEnd, value("15:00"), 
        pushToNextDay, startDay + (startTime > businessEnd), 
        startDayOfWeek, weekday(pushToNextDay, 2), 
        effectiveStartDay, switch(startDayOfWeek, 6, pushToNextDay + 2, 7, pushToNextDay + 1, pushToNextDay), 
        startOutsideBusinessHours, or(startTime > businessEnd, startTime < businessStart, startDayOfWeek > 5), 
        effectiveStartTime, if(startOutsideBusinessHours, businessStart, startTime), 
        daysBetween, max(0, networkdays(effectiveStartDay, endDay) - 2), 
        hoursBetween, daysBetween * (businessEnd - businessStart), 
        hoursStartDay, businessEnd - effectiveStartTime, 
        hoursEndDay, endTime - businessStart, 
        if( 
          effectiveStartDay = endDay, 
          endTime - effectiveStartTime, 
          hoursStartDay + hoursEndDay + hoursBetween 
        ) 
      ), 
      iferror(1/0) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The formula goes to cell `F2`. The results in column `F` look like this:

| Start day | Start time | End day | End time | Response time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-10 Fri | 15:45 | 2023-02-13 Mon | 10:45 | 3:45:00 |
| 2023-02-10 Fri | 7:00 | 2023-02-10 Fri | 9:00 | 2:00:00 |
| 2023-02-10 Fri | 7:00 | 2023-02-10 Fri | 11:00 | 4:00:00 |
| 2023-02-10 Fri | 7:00 | 2023-02-10 Fri | 15:00 | 8:00:00 |
| 2023-02-10 Fri | 7:00 | 2023-02-13 Mon | 9:00 | 10:00:00 |
| 2023-02-10 Fri | 7:00 | 2023-02-13 Mon | 11:00 | 12:00:00 |
| 2023-02-10 Fri | 7:00 | 2023-02-13 Mon | 15:00 | 16:00:00 |
| 2023-02-10 Fri | 7:00 | 2023-02-14 Tue | 9:00 | 18:00:00 |
| 2023-02-10 Fri | 9:00 | 2023-02-14 Tue | 7:00 | 14:00:00 |
| 2023-02-11 Sat | 14:00 | 2023-02-13 Mon | 9:00 | 2:00:00 |
| 2023-02-12 Sun | 14:00 | 2023-02-13 Mon | 9:00 | 2:00:00 |
| 2023-02-12 Sun | 15:00 | 2023-02-13 Mon | 9:00 | 2:00:00 |
| 2023-02-12 Sun | 16:00 | 2023-02-13 Mon | 9:00 | 2:00:00 |
| 2023-02-13 Mon | 6:00 | 2023-02-13 Mon | 9:00 | 2:00:00 |
| 2023-02-13 Mon | 7:00 | 2023-02-13 Mon | 9:00 | 2:00:00 |
| 2023-02-13 Mon | 8:00 | 2023-02-13 Mon | 9:00 | 1:00:00 |
| 2023-02-14 Tue | 9:00 | 2023-02-14 Tue | 9:00 | 0:00:00 |
| 2023-02-20 Mon | 7:00 | 2023-02-27 Mon | 10:00 | 43:00:00 |
| 2023-02-19 Sun | 21:00 | 2023-02-27 Mon | 10:00 | 43:00:00 |

See [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219).

Comment: Thanks. This works