# How to format time duration in a mixed string/number cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a cell that I would like to format as follows (and with the desired values):

`3:15 / 48:00 (-44:45)`

Here is what I have tried (attempting to the use the `TEXT` function):

`=text(sum(B4:4)*24,"hh:mm")&" / "&text(sum(B1:1),"hh:mm")&" ("&text( (sum(B4:4)*24)-sum(B1:1),"hh:mm" )&")"`

However that gives an output of:

`06:00 / 00:00 (06:00)`—the numbers are quizically wrong!

[Please see my reference sheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V6tGQyJSGd3YCh5593Ui0FBkAvmGfxv3uCXgLW7yNhA/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1):

You need to format row 1 as **Format > Number > Duration**.

To format an elapsed time as duration properly, use the `[h]` pattern in `text()`, like this:

`=text(sum(B4:4), "[h]:mm") & " / "& text(sum(B1:1), "[h]:mm") & " (" & text(sum(B4:4) - sum(B1:1), "[h]:mm") & ")"`

See the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V6tGQyJSGd3YCh5593Ui0FBkAvmGfxv3uCXgLW7yNhA/edit#gid=868818783) and [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219).

Comment: Yes I also learned that I could get it to work if my source cells were Duration formatted! Do you know if there is a way to do it starting with regular numbers instead?

Comment: You can convert an integer into a duration of that many hours with `value(int(H2) & ":00")`. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)