# Google Sheets MATCH/VLOOKUP formula searching Date with AM/PM "cannot find value"

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I am trying to return a value based on matching dates that have AM/PM. I have tried **Index/Match** & **ArrayFormula** & **VLookup** Formulas that all should have worked to bring in the value that I'm looking for but each time I get *"Did not find value '44972.75'"* or similar depending on the row. here is the formula

```
=if($A6<>"",INDEX('On-site Totes Pilot'!$E:$E,MATCH($A6,'On-site Totes Pilot'!$O:$O,0)),"")
```

Cell A6 Has **2/15/2023 PM** in it.
And the Range 'On-site Totes Pilot'!$E:$E also has **2/15/2023 PM** in it.

I understand that Google Sheets converts dates to a number but What can I do to make Date 44972.75 match?

Here is a link to a test doc to play with
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yDc1fXIH_S6WxsqFGHi9VUW_d4V5aTeaT7fv5c_xR1c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells that the value in cell `A6` is not the exact date `2023-02-15` but the datetime `2023-02-15 18:00:00`, and that none of the values in the column `'On-site Totes Pilot'!O1:O` match that datetime *exactly*.

To match values as they *appear* in the spreadsheet, use `to_text()`.

The values in 'On-site Totes Pilot!E2:E' are *text strings* that look like `2/17/2023 PM` without a leading zero. The values in 'Chem Usage'!A2:A are *numeric date time values* that look like `02/17/2023   PM` and have a leading zero and two spaces in the middle. To make those inconsistent keys match, use `trim()` and `regexreplace()`.

To look up multiple values in one go, use `vlookup()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      regexreplace(trim(A2:A100), "^0", ""), 
      { trim('On-site Totes Pilot'!E2:E), 'On-site Totes Pilot'!O2:O }, 
      2, false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

In the sample spreadsheet, the formula goes to cell `B2`.

See [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219).

Comment: doubleunary, this did not work for me, I have attached a sheet with example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: The values in 'On-site Totes Pilot!E2:E' are _text strings_ that look like `2/17/2023 PM` without a leading zero. The values in 'Chem Usage'!A2:A are _numeric date time values_ that look like `02/17/2023   PM` and have a leading zero and two spaces in the middle. In other words, you have bad data. Edited the answer to accommodate.