# How to best deal with rounding errors when comparing dates/times

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have a column that contains a series of date/time values
. I am wanting to determine how many of the time slots fall between 10:00 and 11:00 am, 11:00 am and noon, etc. To pull the time out of my date/time entry I am using the formula "=A1 - int(A1)", where A1 is the date/time. However, this is giving me weird rounding errors at the 10th or so decimal place. This error in rounding pulls the extracted time value above or below the "expected" value for a given time, so I hesitate to simply round my values to a given decimal place. How do folks generally work around this?

To give an example, 8 pm is 0.83333333333333. Using the "int" formula to pull the time from my given date, I get 0.833333333328483, making that particular entry be listed as happening between 7 and 8 as opposed to between 8 and 9.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the time portion of a date time value with the `timevalue()` function. It does not suffer from the kind of rounding errors that are unavoidable when subtracting one number from another under the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard used by all major spreadsheet software.

Another easy way to compare the time portion of a date time is to use `text()`, like this:

```
=text(A1, "hh:mm:ss") = text(A2, "hh:mm:ss")
```

See [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219).