# How to extract date and time in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I'm trying to extract the time and date from column A.

> In cell A1 for example is written: October 25, 2023 at 07:23PM
>
> In cell A2 for example is written: October 26, 2023 at 01:01AM

I'm trying to extract the date and time as a formatted 'time / date' value, so that I can calculate the time difference between the two. Note, that the time needs to be formatted in a 24-hour format.

The formula I've tried is this here:

> =TEXT(TIME(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "\d{1,2}"); VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "(\d{2}:\d{2})([AP]M)")) + IF(REGEXMATCH(A1; "PM"); 12; 0)); "HH:mm")

I've also tried already just to extract just the time from it. But it displays then the time wrongly, as 06:28PM is not equal to 06:28 (which would be AM in a 24-hour time format)

> =value(regexextract(A1; "\d{1,1}:\d{2}"))

Comment: Please add more details: the spreadsheet locale (country) ,  the data type of each value (text, number, boolean, date...), the results of the formulas that you tried, etc.

Comment: By the way, we have a lot of questions about handling dates in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That conversion should be quite straightforward when the spreadsheet locale is United States or another locale where the name of the tenth month is `October`. Use `value()` and `split()`, like this:

```
=value(join(" ", split(A1, " at ", false)))
```

Format the formula cell as **Format > Number > Date time** or a custom format of your preference.

To apply a format programmatically, use `query()`, like this:

```
=query( 
  value(join(" ", split(A1, " at ", false))), 
  "format Col1 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm' ", 0 
)
```

When the spreadsheet locale does not recognize `October`, use `regexextract()` and `match()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  t; to_text(A1); 
  year; regexextract(t; "\d{4}"); 
  month; match( 
    regexextract(t; "[A-z]{3}"); 
    hstack("Jan"; "Feb"; "Mar"; "Apr"; "May"; "Jun"; "Jul"; "Aug"; "Sep"; "Oct"; "Nov"; "Dec"); 
    0 
  ); 
  day; regexextract(t; "\d+"); 
  hour; regexextract(t; "(\d+):") + 12 * regexmatch(t; "PM$"); 
  minute; regexextract(t; ":(\d+)"); 
  dateserial; value(join("-"; year; month; day)) + time(hour; minute; 0); 
  query( 
    dateserial; 
    "format Col1 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm' "; 0 
  )
)
```

See See [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219), [regexextract()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3098244), [match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378), [value()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220) and [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343).