# Convert US dates to international format in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I have a Google spreadsheet which I use to track my accounts. I need to add Etsy sales to this, and have added a new sheet which is pasted from the CSV supplied by Etsy.

Unfortunately Etsy only supplies this CSV with dates in US MDY format (e.g. *12/31/2023*) but all of the other dates in my spreadsheet are in the more common DMY format (e.g. *31/12/2023*). As a result, Sheets does not think that these values are dates (or, in cases where it does think they're dates, it misinterprets them).

How can I get Sheets to recognise these dates and re-format them in a way that makes sense? NB I can't change the locale for the entire spreadsheet, because there are many other colums which contain dates in the correct format.

Alternatively (and slightly less ideally) is there a way I can calculate an intermediate value which Sheets will then recognise as a date? I tried this using a simple Regex (e.g. `=REGEXREPLACE(B2, "(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)", "$2/$1/$3")`) but Sheets still does not recognise the resulting value as a date.

Comment: You may want to try the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard date format `yyyy-MM-dd`. It works in any locale.

Comment: That would be ideal, it's what I use for most things, but unfortunately it's not something that Etsy offer - they only give data in US format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `value()`, like this:

```
=to_date(value(regexreplace(B2, "(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)", "$2/$1/$3")))
```

See [value()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220) and [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219)