# Google Sheets - conditional formatting - problem with DATE + 45 days

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I am trying to setup a simple (I thought so anyway) formula using conditional formatting.  I have one cell (B2 for example) that will have a date in it.  Then another cell, lets say K2, we manually put in another date.  All I want to do is, if K2 is 45 days beyond B2, I just want it to highlight the cell K2 in RED.  I can use the default google sheets conditional formatting to make it work if I select TODAY or TOMORROW or YESTERDAY, it functions like I want it.  But I cannot seem to figure out how to determine the formula to use for the conditional formatting to do the same thing if cell K2 is 45 days out from the date in B2...

It seems simple enough, but I can't figure it out.  Could anyone please help?  Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you need? `=K2-45 >= B2`

Answer (score 0):

Use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) rule:

**Greater than or equal to**
`=B2 + 45`

See [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219).